# Why doesn't a String returned from a JTextField recognize special chracters?

Tags: java, jtextfield

So I was just messing around with some JTextFields, trying to print what I was typing into them on a delay, including special characters. I used a javax.swing.Timer to use the ActionListener.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // inputs is an array of 10 JTextFields
    for(int i = 0 ; i < inputs.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(inputs[i].getText().toString());
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n"); // space between each print to the console
}
```

But the console ends up printing exactly what is within the JTextField.(for example, instead of printing a new line, it just prints \n)[image: picture of the code running] The left text is what is being printed to the console, and the right is the JTextFields contained in 'inputs'.

Do you have to do something special when dealing with JTextFields?

Comment: I'm confused. You typed `\n` as your input? Why would that output a new line? You seem to be confused with what `\n` represents in Java _source code_.

Answer (score 2):

There are no special characters here. The only thing in Java that would *translate* your *escape sequences* into the corresponding special characters is the compiler, if they occurred in string literals.

Comment: Shorter, better. 1+

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small test to debug, and I see what you describe (no in `JTextField`, but in `Scanner`, but the symptom is alike). The result in two situations seem inconsistent, but we can know a little more about the mechanism how Java treat and escape characters.

```
package com.WindThunderStudio.PrintLine;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Line 1");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Line 2");
        //output:
        //      Line 1
        //
        //
        //
        //      Line 2
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        //output: "\n" for "\n", no line feed added.
    }
}
```

Some debugging leads us to know that when executing the line of

```
System.out.println("\n");
```

the String is treated without escaping, e.g.,

```
[<line_feed>]
```

, if we look into the Java debugger "Variable" panel when we are in the source code of JDK. Nothing of this string is changed, thus no symbol is escaped.

However, when we read input from the `Scanner`, (in this situation I assume it is very much alike with your case, because reading from `Scanner` and from `JTextField` are both reading user input from the standard `System.in` stream, and produce the same "inconsistency"), the String "\n" will be treated like

```
[\\, n] // (the char '\' is escaped properly)
```

, and no line feed will be detected. Being more concrete, we are talking about the method `write(String s)` in the java.io.PrintStream class:

```
private void write(String s) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(s);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0))
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

Because the character "\" is escaped automatically, it will not be linked with "n" and nothing like "\n" is detected, so no new line feed is added and the input is printed as-is.

It makes me curious actually now why JDK treat these two source of characters so differently, and I assume that when printing with a Java `String` from code, Java compiler sees it **already properly escaped** (if we add some special characters in a String, we must escape them properly to pass the compilation, remember?). But for the user input, so it's more important to escape them as-is, not to check its "meaning" to the system.

Comment: `\n` is processed for escape sequences at compile time, not 'when executing'. The difference is simply that escape sequences in string literals are processed by the compiler, and nothing in the JVM or JRE processes escape sequences at all. No mystery.

Comment: Thanks. Showing my ignorance in order to learn something new.